# Getting maximum without grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

Say that I have a table like that:

```
name | age
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 3
d    | 4
e    | 5
f    | 6
```

Normally, when we select MAX(age), it returns (f,6) tuple. But what I want is that it should return the table as it is, but all of the age values will be the maximum. Such as:

```
name | age
a    | 6
b    | 6
c    | 6
d    | 6
e    | 6
f    | 6
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `name`,
       (SELECT MAX(age) FROM MyTable) AS `age`
FROM MyTable;
```