# SQL Min, Max and also other result

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I've a basic SQL Query, using MySQL:

```
 SELECT
 tgardeub_unidade,
 tgardeub_annee,
 tgardeub_type,
 tunidade_code,
 tunidade_nom
 FROM TAB_GARDE_UBASE
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB_UNIDADE
 ON tunidade_id = tgardeub_unidade
 ORDER BY tgardeub_annee, tgardeub_type, tgardeub_unidade
```

which give me 6 results and that's OK. The field tgardeub_annee give the year of the data and on these 6 results, the range came from 2015 to 2018. 
What I want is to get the same 6 results but also, at the same time, the Min value of the year and the Max value. So, one more column with 2015 and one more with 2018.
I thought it was possible using simply:

```
 SELECT
 tgardeub_unidade,
 tgardeub_annee,
 tgardeub_type,
 tunidade_code,
 tunidade_nom,
 MIN(tgardeub_annee) AS first_year,
 MAX(tgardeub_annee) AS last_year
 FROM TAB_GARDE_UBASE
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB_UNIDADE
 ON tunidade_id = tgardeub_unidade
 ORDER BY tgardeub_annee, tgardeub_type, tgardeub_unidade
```

so just adding the two lines, one with Min the other with Max. This query give me first_year=2015 and last_year=2018 (which is right), but unfortunaly, it give only one line of result!

And using EXPLAIN don't help as in the two cases, I get the same "explaination". Do I have to perform a previous small query with only the Min and Max or is there a solution to get at the same time the 6 results AND the Max and Min value of all the results?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712660/mysql-getting-maximum-without-grouping which is a similar question and the accepted answer should help you

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must admit I was afraid of the fact to need a double query, and the answer confirm I was right to be. :)